# How to use out of multi line command out in a foreach loop in a bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop, foreach

When i run this command i get this output

```
# ods-ksmutil key export --zone 231.72.212.in-addr.arpa --ds | grep "8 2"
231.72.212.in-addr.arpa.        3600 IN DS      45767 8 2 93f383a81ff2c124bdd395f51e58b88317cb8852facd93d3f6f30efdd2afa5b8
231.72.212.in-addr.arpa.        3600 IN DS      16076 8 2 285561f87150d40a245daeb141a61ceebf8e966924d8d868327d42ba483bef00
231.72.212.in-addr.arpa.        3600 IN DS      12845 8 2 85e7b92455d73f59ed8968e1992bb2c3a9d57a674283496cac5b3020a1d2e258
```

For each line i want execute a command  like this in case off line 1 that whil be:

```
command 45767 8 2 93f383a81ff2c124bdd395f51e58b88317cb8852facd93d3f6f30efdd2afa5b8
```

I don't know to get this working in some kind of foreach loop

Who can help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this:

`| awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8}' | xargs -L 1 command`

or remove your `grep "8 2"` and add this:

`| awk '/8 2/ {print $5,$6,$7,$8}' | xargs -L 1 command`

Comment: Why remove the grep , the grep is to get the output i need

Comment: Thanks this the best sollution for me

Comment: The second awk combines your `grep "8 2"` and `awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8}'` in one command.

Answer (score 4):

You can use process substitution:

```
while read -ra a; do
  command "${a[4]}" "${a[5]}" "${a[6]}" "${a[7]}"
done < <(ods-ksmutil key export --zone 231.72.212.in-addr.arpa --ds | grep "8 2")
```

Answer (score 1):

In a script you can do that like:

```
for line in ${ods-ksmutil key export --zone 231.72.212.in-addr.arpa --ds | grep "8 2"}
    command ${echo $line | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 5-8}
done
```

That requires that the IFS is set to the newline character which it should be by default.